# Justify text from post into Visual Composer grid

Tags: wordpress, justify, visual-composer

### What I have

A 2 item grid created with WPBakery Visual Composer Version 4.11.2.1. Inside every item of the grid there is there is a post from my news section.

### What i need to do

I need to justify the text inside grid's item

Comment: Which visual composer you are talking about? is it of any theme?

Comment: Visual composer version added to original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 'Grid element template'.

Here is the step to create template:

- Go to Visual Composer > Grid Elements menu
- Add 'Grid Element' title (e.g 'My custom template')
- Click on 'Templates' icon (pop up window 'grid templates' will be opened)
- Select 'Basic Grid: Default' from grid templates
- New column will be appended at bottom of template
- Click on edit button of 'Post Excerpt' (pop up window 'Post Excerpt Settings will be opened')
- Select 'Div' option from 'Element tag' drop down
- Select 'Justify' option from 'Text align' drop down
- Click on 'Save changes'
- Click on 'Publish' to publish grid element

Now you need to select 'Grid Element Template' from 'Post Grid Settings' :

- Go to 'Grid Settings' (Click on edit button of grid element)
- Go to 'Item Design' tab.
- Select `Template Name` option from 'Grid element template' drop down (Template name  is the template that is created in above steps. E.g 'My custom template')
- Click on 'Save Changes'

If you need more explanation for the steps, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just Press alt+shift+j in every text block!